# Update the same names on different row using loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with combobox 9 when you select combobox9 value it will show all the values into the each boxes and you can updated the textbox 19 value into sheet against the raw of the selected value in combobox9 however problem is if there's the same name e.g. twice same name in combobox9 it will only update the its 1st name on the raw and not the 2nd or even if there is 3 entry in sheet with same name.

Names are in column C and textvalue is updated its name on column H however I need to loop the column H if it is already updated against its name then same name needs to updated which is in new raw.

Below is the vba code I have but it is so far not working

```
Dim lCol As Variant
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Attendance")

    If Me.ComboBox9.Value <> "" Then

If VBA.CVar(Application.Match(VBA.CVar(Me.ComboBox9.Value), sh.Range("C:C"), 0)) = True Then

MsgBox "Record Not found", vbCritical

Exit Sub

Else

i = Application.Match(VBA.Cvar(Me.ComboBox9.Value), sh.Range("C:C"), 0)

End If

lCol = Me.ComboBox9.Value

Set findvalue = sh.Range("C:C").Find(What:=lCol, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not findvalue Is Nothing Then

adr = findvalue.Address

Do

If findvalue.Offset(0, 6).Value = Me.TextBox19 Then

sh.Unprotect "1234"

findvalue.Offset(0, 6).Value = Me.TextBox19.Value = ""

Exit Do

End If

Set findvalue = sh.Range("C:C").FindNext(findvalue)

Loop While findvalue.Address <> adr

Set findvalue = Nothing

End If
```

Comment: Hi Bra thank you correcting. can you please help me i am really stuck with the code.

Comment: You should get in the habit of indenting your code - makes it much easier to follow. Perhaps your Do loop is being exited because `findvalue.Offset(0, 6).Value = Me.TextBox19`?

Comment: i want textbox19 value only to be updated in column "i" against the combobox9 selection which is in column C. it need to find an empty cell in column "i" once you select from the combobox9 as there may be multiply entries of the same name in column C